# Google Apps Script: is there some way to put submenus in submenus?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to put submenus in a submenu in a Google spreadsheet using `addMenu(name, subMenus)` or an alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes :) but not using `addMenu(name, subMenus)`; instead, using `addSubMenu`.

Please refer [Custom menus in Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms).

[image: Custom Menus in G Suite]

Here's the code -

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu1')
          .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2').addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu2')
          .addItem('Third item', 'menuItem3')))
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .alert('You clicked the first menu item!');
}

function menuItem2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .alert('You clicked the second menu item!');
}

function menuItem3() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .alert('You clicked the third menu item!');
}
```

As far as I can tell, there are no documented restrictions in the number of sub-menus you can create, inside a sub-menu.

Hope this helps!